# How I delete a complete feature from my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, rails-models

Initially I built a forum on rails with the user and the post model but now I am planning to pivot to something else and *I don't need the posts functionality anymore.*

My question is **how do I completely delete** it and what would be **correct order** if I have to just delete the files generated.

By deleting I mean everything like that feature never existed in the app, no database connections and no properties remaining on the other user model.

I am not sure how I do I proceed, there are many ways to do it, by running commands or by just deleting the generated files but I want to know the **correct way** because **I don't want to run into trouble** if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "correct" way, just delete the files, create a migration removing the tables and then audit your remaining files for methods that are no longer used.

In simple cases, you can use the generators that generated your code to also remove that code. If you used `rails generate model MyModel` to produce your model and migration, you can use `rails destroy model MyModel`.